# how to pass params in rspec when testing for a mailer method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

```
expect(UserMailer).to receive(UserMailer.addon_purchased).with(event_order_id: @event_order.id)
```

I am using the above code.
What are the changes do I need to make this work?

My mailer method

```
@event_order = EventOrder.find(params[:event_order_id])

    # TECH DEBT: why is .first relevant?
    @ticket = @event_order.addons.first.event_ticket
    if @ticket.blank?
      Rails.logger.error "ticket purchased but no ticket found for Order# - #{@event_order.id}"
      raise StandardError.new("ticket not found")
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `addon_purchased` is a class method, you need to modify the code as follows

```
expect(UserMailer).to receive(:addon_purchased).with(event_order_id: @event_order.id)
```

Refer:
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages

Comment: My mail is being sent after purchasing a product and it includes filling a card and payment gateway is nexiopay. But instead of showing the card it is showing me " Missing required request parametres: [token]". Do you know something of it ?